# Regex positive lookahead to period or / whichever comes first?

Tags: regex

say I have

```
job.batch/monitoring-cloud12390200
```

or

```
service/monitoring-opentt-collector
```

I want to match `job` in the first and `service` in the second.

I know I can use positive lookahead to match the string up to and if it has a `/` by using `.*((?=\/))`

But this will give me `job.batch` in the first

What I want to do is match the string up to the first `/` or `.`, whichever comes first.

Comment: You can try `.*?(?=[\/.])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex:

```py
^[^\/.]+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/ytIz53/1)

| NODE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `[^\/.]+` | any character except: '/', '.' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

Comment: oh thank you so much! I guess when writing regular expressions it's easy to get so focused on doing it a certain way, that it's helpful to completely start over and think of other ways to go about it.